# CSS3 border radius on 2 spans within heading, is this effect possible?

Tags: css

I'd like to achieve the shape I've posted in link below for all my h2s on a page. I have a rough idea how I could do it using png background images with a couple of spans inside the heading perhaps.

http://vurtmedia.net/header.png

Any ideas on if this would be possible in pure CSS? I'd much prefer this, as I am not bothered about IE9 or lower in this instance.

Sorry if my post description isn't the best, not sure how to describe this shape!

Thanks in advance :)

Pat

Comment: It would be helpful, if you post the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: ohhhhh wait... this is about canvas...

Comment: is it really? because if it is, then why are you referring to using CSS3?

Comment: Sorry, I thought canvas could come into it somewhere? As I said I thought my description was a bit bad already due to not really knowing how to describe the shape!

Answer (score 0):

You could just set a padding, border radius and use absolute positioning in order to get the positions of the elements straight, see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/496EG/)

HTML:

```
 <h1 class="shaded">lorem</h1>
 <h2 class="shaded bottomright">ipsum</h2>
```

CSS:

```
.shaded
{
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#000;
    border-radius:12px;
    font-family:verdana;
}

.topleft
{

}

.bottomright
{
    position:absolute;
    left:40px;
    top:6px;
}

h1
{
    font-size:20px;
    color:#FFF;
    display:inline-block;
}

h2
{
    font-size:60px;
    color:#FFF;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

But that does not allow you to smooth the corners between the two elements, which is not possible to achieve in CSS only.
You could smooth the corners out with pictures, but that would leave you with some positioning problems.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)

This is where I got with it, very similar -  http://www.vurtmedia.net/heading-test.html 

Was wondering if there was a CSS trick or something that could achieve that last bit - the smoothing between the elements. I guess just using one png with that smoothing curve positioned right on the first span could do it?

Comment: I took a look at using CSS3 box shadows, but there's no way of getting rid of the blurryness.